# replace strings in textbox which contain listbox items

Tags: arrays, vb.net, replace, textbox, listbox

i have 2 listboxed and 1 textbox.
the textbox contains a text file with words in it.
listbox 1 contain these words that need to be translated and listbox 2 contain the translated words.

now i am trying to replace these but i keep getting an error.
also it doesnt loop trough the listboxes.

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        For x As Integer = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
            If TextBox1.Contains(ListBox1.Items(i)) Then
                TextBox1.Text.Replace(ListBox1.Items(i), ListBox2.Items(x))
            End If
        Next
    Next i
```

Comment: `TextBox1.Text.Contains`?  There is no `Contains` method for the `TextBox` class, right?

Comment: @nhgrif , it does exist.

Answer (score 0):

When interacting with dynamic lits its better to use the for each statament.

And example:

```
For Each i As String In ListBox1.Items
    For Each x As String In ListBox2.Items
         If TextBox1.Contains(i) Then
             TextBox1.Text = x
         End If
    Next
Next
```

Note that, i and x are ListBox items so oyu may have to type then, to compare to the TextBox string.

Comment: ToList cannot be found.

Comment: Because Items is a Collection, not necessary a List. And the For Each may doesn't work without this. You could try without the Tolist but i'm not sure it will work.

Comment: You could try just For Each ListBox.Items

Comment: I have edit the code, i think now it should work. This is the main idea, try to modidy to your needs.

Comment: Error 1 Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'.

Comment: This example works fine for me:

        Dim x As New ListBox
        x.Items.Add("dsada")


        'For Each word As String In x.Items
            Dim xs = word
        Next'

Comment: @AppieZemmouri please try this copy to your source code and let me know the results

inline
        'Dim x As New ListBox
        Dim y As New ListBox
        Dim text As New TextBox With {.Text = "old"}
        x.Items.Add("old")
        y.Items.Add("changed")
        For Each word As String In x.Items
            For Each translate As String In y.Items
                If text.Text.Equals(word) Then
                    text.Text = translate
                End If
            Next
        Next '